# async/await,не выводит результаты

Tags: c#, android-asynctask

Решил почитать про async/await как советовали тут и вот что из этого получилось

Взяв за основу несколько примеров,получил такой блок кода

```
static Task<double> getresulting(int frc,int frc1,double shag,double U,double T)
        {
            int t = 0;
            double resulting = 0;
            NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {

                   resulting = (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(angularFrequency => GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T)) * Math.Cos(angularFrequency * t), 0, frc1);
                return resulting;
            });
        }
```

Затем метод из за которого у меня всё тормозилось сделал его async-методом.
И передаю  `static Task<double> getresulting`

В строке `double resulting = await getresulting(frc, frc1, shag, U, T);`

Делаю как и полагается пишу await,вызов getresulting

```
public async void drawreverse(double U, double T, double shag, int frc, int frc1)
        {
            GraphPane panel77 = zedGraphControl2.GraphPane;
            //NumericalIntegration integration = new NumericalIntegration();
            //double t = 0;
            panel77.Title.Text = "Обратное преобразование";
            panel77.XAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            panel77.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsVisible = true;
            panel77.YAxis.MajorGrid.IsZeroLine = false;
            panel77.XAxis.Title.Text = "f,кГЦ";
            panel77.YAxis.Title.Text = "U(f), мВ*с";
            PointPairList list1 = new PointPairList();

            for (double fr = frc; fr <= frc1; fr += shag)
            {
              double resulting = await getresulting(frc, frc1, shag, U, T);
                list1.Add(fr, resulting);
            }

            panel77.AddCurve("", list1, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);

            panel77.XAxis.Scale.Min = xmin_limit;
            panel77.XAxis.Scale.Max = xmax_limit;

            panel77.YAxis.Scale.Min = ymin_limit;
            panel77.YAxis.Scale.Max = ymax_limit;

            zedGraphControl2.AxisChange();
            zedGraphControl2.Invalidate();
        }
```

Программа компилируется и работает но ничего не выводит на ZedGraphControl2.

Цикл не убираю потому что по нему идёт заполнение точек и я предположил что буду вызывать task getresulting при каждом шаге и заносить точку на координату

Comment: А если поставить breakpoint на `list1.Add(fr, resulting);`? Посмотрите, какие значения приходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не выводите ничего между вычислениями частей. У вас await-вызов вычисляет одну точку результата, который затем складывается в `list1`. И только после окончания всей работы `list1` скармливается графику. Если вы хотите обновление после каждой подсчитанной точки, добавляйте данные на `zedGraphControl2` после каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: Могу ли я сделать правку вопроса ?

Как я понял, под добавление данных на ZedGraphControl2 после каждой итерации цикла, понимается это

 for (double fr = frc; fr <= frc1; fr += shag)
            {
                double resulting = (1 / (2 * Math.PI)) * integration.Calculate(angularFrequency => GetSpectralDensityOfAmplitude(GetSpectralDensity(U, angularFrequency, T)) * Math.Cos(angularFrequency * t), 0, frc1);
                 resulting = await getresulting(frc, frc1, shag, U, T);
                list1.Add(fr, resulting);
            }
Дело в том что так тоже пусто.

Comment: @beginner: Да, конечно, дополняйте.